# Mongo How to find all documents based on a dynamic property in objects in array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
documents in my sb:

{
{prop1: "abc", otherProp: "xxx",...},
{prop1: "x", otherProp: "xxx",...}
}
```

```
const arr = [{prop1: "abc", otherProp: "xxx",...},{prop1: "y", otherProp: "xxx",...}];
```

1. How do I find the document with property where prop1 is "abc" ?
   2.. all the documents where prop1 is not "abc"?

```
await db.collection.find({prop1: "arr.$.prop1"})
```

is not the proper way to do it but how do I access dynamic properties in the array of objects?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear what do you intend to do with the variable `arr`?

Comment: so what I actually want to do is add all the objects/documents from arr to my collection if no document in my collection has (lets say) prop1 with same value. so im my case i only add those 2 objects in arr to db, if there is no prop1 with either "abc" value or 'y' value. So im trying to understand how i can iterate through arr and compare a dynamic value with value in db. hope that was more clear and thanks for responsing!

Comment: In your case `abc` is present but `y` is not present, so do you want to insert the doc with `y` into the database?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Answer (score 0):

One way is to loop over the array and do upsert operations. Like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   await db.collection.updateOne({prop1: arr[i].prop1}, {$set: arr[i]}, {upsert: true});
}
```

This will update the document, if it's already there, otherwise insert it.
If you don't want to update the document just insert the new ones, try this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   const doc = await db.collection.findOne({prop1: arr[i].prop1});
   if (!!doc) {
      await db.collection.insertOne(arr[i]);
   }
}
```

If you are using Mongoose, use `Model.findOne` and `Model.save`.

Comment: thank you. i did that now accept i use const new Model(arr[i]).save() as insertOne is not recognized by mongoose. do you know perhaps, how I can save that new document sorted (lets say by createdAt)?

Comment: We can't specify sort order during the insert operation, we have to sort the documents, when we fetch them using `find` method.

Comment: Hope that clarifies @juliascoding.

Comment: so if I use $push for example, I can sort data before adding them to the db. perhaps there is something else I can use to also be able in this case?

Comment: $push is used for pushing an element within an  array in  a document, and you want to have that array sorted, then we use $sort.

Comment: We can order elements in an array, but we can't order the elements in the collection, because we don't know the underlying data structure

Comment: Indexes are sorted. Do you want to use them @juliascoding

Comment: so I can index a field in my document and then all documents in the collection will be sorted based on that index field?

Comment: When you index a field in your document, and you use that key for filtering or sorting, your index will be used, to filter or sort the data which is much faster, as compared to scanning through the collection and filtering and sorting. @juliascoding